# Is it possible to save binaries that pip compiles while installing a package?

Tags: compiling, pip, virtualenv

I'm working on a project for a Raspberry Pi 3.
One of the things my project requires is cython.

Running `pip install cython` on a Raspberry Pi inside of a virtualenv takes about 40 minutes to complete, as cython apparently needs to be compiled first. During these 40 minutes, `top` shows cc running, trying to compile stuff, using 100% of one core.

I need to do this several times every day, as I keep needing to reset the SD card to a fresh image of Raspbian. This is obviously very time-consuming, and is slowing down progress.

When pip is done compiling cython, where are the binaries stored? Inside the virtualenv? Somewhere else on the filesystem?

If they are stored in the virtualenv, can I archive the entire virtualenv folder, and restore it to a fresh Linux, and expect it to work? I know virtualenvs aren't supposed to be portable (without using the `--relocatable` arg, which seems to have its own issues), but in my case, the path of the virtualenv will remain the same when I restore it.

Comment: If you are putting the same binaries in the same distribution with the same hardware, you should only compile it once, save and copy as necessary.  Pip will store files in the virtualenv and tracks where it places each file, use `pip show -f somepackage` to see where `pip` placed all the files resulting from compiling `sompackage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy the wheel file from the cache dir. When `pip install pkgname` is issued and `pip` doesn't find a compatible wheel to install from, it builds one from the source dist and stores it in cache to reuse for future reinstalls. To find the wheel file, issue

```
$ find $HOME/.cache/pip -type f -name Cython*.whl
```

Backup the file; to install from the local file, just issue

```
$ pip install path/to/file.whl
```

#### Where to go from here: local repository

When you have a lot of prebuilt wheels collected, the next step would be setting up a local PyPI repository to install from. The simplest way is to organize the wheels into package-named dirs and run a simple HTTP server:

```
└── repodir
    ├── Cython
    │   └── Cython-0.28.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_aarch64.whl
    ...
```

Start the server with e.g.

```
$ python3 -m http.server -p 9000
```

Now you can pass the repo to `pip`:

```
$ pip install Cython --extra-index-url=http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

or even persist the repo URL in the `pip.conf` to not to enter it each time:

```
# pip.conf
[global]
extra-index-url=http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

Should you look for more, there are lots of fancy PyPI repo servers out there like `devpi` which offer versatile package management, web UI etc.

Comment: It looks like when using virtualenvs, the wheel files are stored inside the virtual env. Archiving the virtualenv with tar, and later restoring it to a clean Linux worked with no issues, and sped up the process of setting up a fresh Linux considerably. Thanks for the idea of a local repo - I might do that.